# Implementacion de colas en java

Tags: java

El ejercicio me pide simular el control de una cola para compra de entradas de un cine
Como podria lograr que me cuente la cantidad de personas que entraron en la sala de cine y las que no, habiendo todas comprado entradas, alguna pista? Este es el codigo de mi main class

```
public class AplicacionCine {

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int Precio1= 20000;
        final int Precio2= 30000;
        final int Precio3 = 50000;
        Cola<Persona> cola = new Cola<>();
        llenarCola(cola);
        int rec1=0, rec2=0 ,rec3=0,rectot=0; 
       Persona n;
       while(!cola.isEmpty()){
           n=cola.descolar();
           if(n.getEdad()>=5 && n.getEdad()<=10){
               rec1+= Precio1;
           }else if(n.getEdad()>=11 && n.getEdad()<=17){
               rec2+= Precio2;
           }else{
               rec3+= Precio3;
           }
       }
        System.out.println("Se ha recaudado"+rec1);
        System.out.println("Se ha recaudado"+rec2);
        System.out.println("Se ha recaudado"+rec3);
    }
    public static void llenarCola(Cola<Persona> cola){
          int cantPers= 5 +(int)(Math.random()*20);
          System.out.println("se generan"+cantPers+"personas");
        Persona n;
        int anio;
          for(int i=0; i<cantPers; i++){
              anio = 5+(int)(Math.random()*60);
              
              
              n= new Persona(anio);
              System.out.println("Se ha generado una persona con"+n.getEdad());
              cola.encolar(n);
              
            
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Podria hacerlo utilizando otra cola?

Comment: Tu codigo no compila porque no agregaste la clase Cola